# Modify the metamodel's schema to change/rename column names

Tags: java, apache-metamodel

I am using Apache MetaModel to get the schema information. There is one use case, where I need to create `CsvDataContext` object for csv file with no header. I have column names in a separate data structure (`List<String> colNames`).

The `context` object gives column names as `"A", "B", "C", etc`. I guess metamodel assigns some default column names to the tables with no headers.

Is there any way to modify the schema which is held by the `CsvDataContext` object?

I believe `UpdateableDataContext` should work, but the documentation doesn't expose any method that allows modifying the metadata like column name.

How is it possible to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `CsvDataContext`, you specify a `CsvConfiguration`. One of the options in the `CsvConfiguration` is to provide a `ColumnNamingStrategy`. The default strategy is in deed to use alphabetic characters, `A`, `B`, `C` etc. But you can use a custom naming strategy, like this:

```
ColumnNamingStrategy columnNamingStrategy =
    ColumnNamingStrategies.customNames("id", "foo", "bar", "baz");
CsvConfiguration configuration = new CsvConfiguration(
    0, columnNamingStrategy, "UTF-8", ',', '"', '\\', true, false);
return new CsvDataContext(file, configuration);
```